# Translate MVC Ajax.ActionLink to jQuery .post method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am dealing with this ASP.NET MVC problem of that using ValidateAntiForgeryToken with AJAX breaks the AJAX call ([Using ValidateAntiForgeryToken with Ajax.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786500/using-validateantiforgerytoken-with-ajax-actionlink)). The only solution (as stated in that topic) requires jQuery.

How do i do the eqvivalent of the following with jQuery's .post method?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Perform HTTPPost", "PostTest", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="POST"})
```

Here is the Controller:

```
// [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public class MoreInfoController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostTest()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is it's Index VIEW with both Javascript and HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#linkToPost').click(PostForm);
    });

    function PostForm() {
        $.post("/PostTest", $('#testForm').serialize(), function(data) {

        });
        return false;
    }

</script>
<a id="linkToPost" href="#">Perform HTTP Post</a>
<form id="testForm" method="POST" >
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

And here is the Route:

```
routes.MapRoute("PostTest1",
                            "PostTest",
                            new {controller = "MoreInfo", action = "PostTest"}
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

My example is using $.ajax but you can easily change it to $.post

```
@Html.ActionLink("Perform HTTP Post", "PostTest", "Controller", null, new { id = "someId" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#someId').click(function() {
            $.post({
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data) {
                    // assuming you're returning a partial result
                    $('#somecontainer').html(data);
                }
            });

            // prevent the default action
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to give the anchor an id, you could use a class selector:

```
$('.ajax-link').click(function() { ... });
```

Instead of doing `new { id = "someId" }` you would need to do `new { @class = "ajax-link" }` or whatever you wanted your class to be named.

**edit**
I was using the wrong overload. I was trying to set the id for the html attribute, not the route data.

Comment: What is the ID? I don't use that.

Comment: I just gave the anchor tag an id so that I can find it via an id selector with jQuery. You don't need to use it if you have some other way to select the tag so that you can attach a click handler.

Comment: Actually I am in the View (index.cshtml) that has the @Asp.AntiForgeryToken() at the top. I also have the Ajax.ActionLink in this view ONLY for the purpose of testing this issue of AntiForgeryToken making AJAX calls fail (see link above). I am trying to post to it's controller (MoreInfoController) where there is an Action Method PostTest(). I want to post to that. That controller has the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

Comment: Ok, I left the anchor tag as someId and just changed to @Html.ActionLink("Perform HTTP Post", "PostTest", "MoreInfoController", null, new { id = "someId" }). I cannot get it to hit that method in the controller.

Comment: Your code does a POST but I cannot get it to Post to the method "PostTest"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your anti forgery token element is in the form you want to post you can do the following:

Here is your link:

```
<a id="linkToPost" href="#">Perform HTTP Post</a>
```

Here is the jquery to bind the click of this link to post the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#linkToPost').click(PostForm);   
});
function PostForm() {
    $.post("/PostTest", $('#idOfyourForm').serialize(), function(data) {
      // do something with the data that comes back from the post 
    });
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Now what you need to do is replace `#idOfYourForm` with the actual id of your form:

`<form id="TestForm">` you would make it `$('#TestForm').serialize()`

Next you need to make sure the route I have of `/PostTest` will actually map to your controller and action.  You will need something like this:

```
context.MapRoute("PostTest1",
                 "PostTest",  // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "MoreInfoController", action = "PostTest" });
```

That's it.

Comment: Actually I am in the View (index.cshtml) that has the @Asp.AntiForgeryToken() at the top. I also have the Ajax.ActionLink in this view ONLY for the purpose of testing this issue of AntiForgeryToken making AJAX calls fail (see link above). I am trying to post to it's controller (MoreInfoController) where there is an Action Method PostTest(). I want to post to that. That controller has the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

Comment: @SamGentile - As long as your AntiForgeryToken helper is in the form you are going to post, then it should pass the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your action.  I'm currently doing this on my project without any issues.

Comment: It does not work for Ajax methods. See original link in my pst above.

Comment: @SamGentile - It will work with jquery ajax methods as long as the token is in the form you are serializing

Comment: Your code by itself doesn't seem to do anything. Again, I am trying to post to get to the PostTest method in the controller. It doesn't even show a link on the form for me to perform the test. If I combine in with @Html.ActionLink("Perform HTTP Post", "PostTest", "MoreInfo", null, new { id = "someId" }) it generates the right URL but still doesn't seem to hit the breakpoint in the PostTest method of the MoreInfo controller.

Comment: @SamGentile - you just asked for a translation of a ajax.actionlink to a post call. I supplied that information originally.  See my edit for everything you wanted.

Comment: I just edited to everything of your last edit and nothing happens when I click "Perform HTTP Post"

Comment: When yoy say "Form", you mean "View" right? This is in Index.cshtml

Comment: @SamGentile - No form is the form tag which you need to have in order to post any value back to a server

Comment: I didn't think you needed a form to do the Ajax post. Th eother solution is changing the Get to a Post. Can you show the form on your solution?

Comment: I put a <form id="testForm"></form> on the view and I still get nothing when I click the link.

Comment: @SamGentile - Here is a jsfiddle example of the jquery code working: http://jsfiddle.net/KGwN9/

Comment: @SamGentile - You do need a form when doing a serialize in jquery to grab the form elements to post over to the server.  This is the easiest way to grab the antiforgery token element that is inserted into the page when you use the html helper to create it.  If you don't post it with your form then your validateantiforgerytoken attibute will fail.

Comment: @SamGentile - why don't you post your code and I can see what is wrong.  Include your action, html, your route and javascript.

Comment: @SamGentile - Put it at the bottom of your question by editing it.

Comment: Ok, amurra, I put the code at the bottom of my question. BTW, thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @SamGentile - You code looks fine, does it not hit the breakpoint in the action?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
[UseAntiForgeryTokenOnPostByDefault]

    public class MoreInfoController: Controller
    {
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult PostTest()
       {
           return View();
       }
    }
```

And the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "MoreInfo")
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

where [UseAntiForgeryTokenOnPostByDefault] is http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/04.aspx