# Convert the asp.net action link to jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I loop the data from database to create the menu. This is my code :

```
<% 
string strBrand  = Request.QueryString["brand"]; 
string strSearch = Request.QueryString["search"];
%>

<div id="content">
  <ul id='navmenu-v'>        
    <% foreach (var a in Model.Department){ %>

    <li>  
     <% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSearch))
        {%>

        <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
        new { dep = a.ID, search = strSearch, tab = Model.Tab }, 
        new { @class = "selectedcategory" })%>       
     <%  } else {%>

        <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
        new { dep = a.ID, tab = Model.Tab }, new { @class = "selectedcategory" })%>    
     <%   } %>

     </li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

And now I want to convert this code into some things like ajax or jquery, to prevent reload the page 
while click on the link.

This is what I have tried to do :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetMenuList";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {

            $("#navmenu-v").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='list'>" + 
            dataOption.Name + "</a></li>");

        });

      });

  });

  </script>
```

This code I can get the list of menu, but I have no idea how to create this link like

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, new { dep = a.ID, 
search = strSearch, tab = Model.Tab }, new { @class = "selectedcategory" })%>
```

Thanks you so much. And welcome to all yours answers.

Comment: Hiya, is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894273/translate-mvc-ajax-actionlink-to-jquery-post-method , hope it helps, cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit : Thanks Tats_innit, but I don't need to post to the form.